# How to link an SQL Database in Visual Studio to Razor cshtml?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I was following this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data
but I am doing this in Visual Studio instead of WebMatrix since there is no more support for WebMatrix anymore. I tried creating a database within Visual Studio, but I'm not sure how to reference it with C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Also if possible link it to a Microsoft Access database.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is already configured on your project, you must first open the connection in your cshtml header or whatever

```
var db = Database.Open("DATABASENAME");
```

The Database must be connected with a few line in the Web.config page (This kind of informationS)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DATABASENAME" connectionString="server=Servername;database=DATABASENAME;trusted_connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add connectionString="Server=.\DATABASE STRING;Database=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=True" name="DATABASE NAME" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```